# How can I find out what's changing the return address of a function in c++

Tags: c++, debugging, memory, undefined-behavior

I have a program that behaves weirdly and probably has undefined behaviour. Sometimes, the return address of a function seems to be changed, and I don't know what's causing it.

The return address is always changed to the same address, an assertion inside a function the control shouldn't be able to reach. I've been able to stop the program with a debugger to see that when it's supposed to execute a return statement, it jumps straight to the line with the assertion instead.

This code approximates how my function works.

```
int foo(Vector t)
   double sum = 0;
   for(unsgined int i=0; i<t.size();++i){
        sum += t[i]; 
   }
   double limit = bar(); // bar returns a value between 0 and 1
   double a=0;
   for(double i=0; i<10; i++){
       a += f(i)/sum; // f(1)/sum + ... + f(10)/sum = 1.0f
       if(a>3)return a;
   }
   //shoudn'get here
   assert(false); // ... then this line is executed
}
```

This is what I've tried so far:

- Switching all std::vector `[]` operators with `.at` to prevent accidentily writing into memory
- Made sure all return-by-value values are const.
- Switched on `-Wall` and `-Werror` and `-pedantic-errors` in gcc
- Ran the program with valgrind

I get a couple of `invalid read of size 8`, but they seem to originate from qt, so I'm not sure what to make of it. Could this be the problem?

The error happens only occasionally when I have run the program for a while and give it certain input values, and more often in a release build than in a debug build.

**EDIT:**
So I managed to reproduce the problem in a console application (no qt loaded) I then manages to simulate events that caused the problem.

Like some of you suggested, it turns out I misjudged what was actually causing it to reach the assertion, probably due to my lack of experience with qt's debugger. The actual problem was a floating point error in the double i used as a loop condition.

I was implementing softmax, but exp(x) got rounded to zero with particular inputs.

Now, as I have solved the problem, I might rephrase it. Is there a method for checking problems like rounding errors automatically. I.e breaking on 0/0 for instance?

Comment: Are you sure that this is corrupted return address? Looks like the loop ended without executing `return a`

Comment: In this code you'll get there (0+1+2 < 3). If the example is a mistake try debug printing and manual binary search.

Comment: Sorry, mistake on my part. Edited the example. It's not my actual code, though. I added a breakpoint on the line that returns, and when I stepped to the next line, it's gets to a line somewhere in the start of the function. Then it jumps straight to the assertion.

Comment: If the example code you posted doesn't show the problem then I'm not sure what value it has. Ideally, you'd post example code that could be compiled and run to reproduce the error. But if that's not possible for whatever reason, it would probably be better to post a snippet of your actual code (even if it isn't complete enough to compile).

Comment: It sounds like there might be a problem with your loop condition that isn't being shown in your example. Have you examined the assembly to see what is actually happening?

Comment: http://ideone.com/Zyrpkq shows that this works. could you give us some more of the relevant code please?

Comment: Since this happens only occasionally, I suspect some other part of the code is corrupting the call stack. Make sure you're not letting pointers to local variables outlive the variable's scope, or deleting objects prematurely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is:

> The most portable way of determining if a floating-point exceptional condition has occurred is to use the floating-point exception facilities provided by C in fenv.h.

although, unfortunately, this is far from being perfect.

I suggest you to read both
https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/FLP04-C.+Check+floating-point+inputs+for+exceptional+values
and
https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/FLP03-C.+Detect+and+handle+floating-point+errors
which concisely address the exact question you are posing:

> Is there a method for checking problems like rounding errors automatically.